# Align UILabel Text to bottom left corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, alignment, uilabel

I have a UILabel that is positioned on top of a UIImageView. The text can be various lengths, so it is necessary that I make the label as large as possible (The same size frame as the imageView). The problem is, I don't want the text from the label to cover the image by being directly in the center of the image. It's easy to set left alignment in a UILabel. Any clue how to set vertical alignment as well? Basically I want the text to hug the bottom left corner no matter what length it is without being cut off.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can accomplish this with Autolayout. If you set up your constraints so that the label is fixed to the bottom left, but don't set a height constraint, Autolayout will use the label's Intrinsic Content Size. This just means that as the label gets more text / changes font / etc, the label will grow in height and will only ever be tall enough to contain all the text in the label.

Comment: wow that was incredibly easy! Thanks! I just pinned it to the bottom and the left